# Would a cpu fan turn if the processor is dead?

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard, fan

so I kind of left my laptop at 100% load for two weeks strait, and it turned off and wouldn't turn on again. A week later it turned on, then next time I shut it down, it wouldn't turn on again.

Anyway, So I took apart the laptop, and I'm trying to figure out what parts to replace.

when the power button is pressed, nothing happens. At all. No lights, the cpu fan doesn't jerk, nothing.

So I took the laptop apart, and I'm looking at the motherboard as I press the power button, and again nothing happens at all.

So, either the cpu or the motherboard is fried. I'm curious what happens if you turn on a motherboard with a dead cpu or no cpu? will lights still go on? will the cpu fan try to turn? if the answer is no, then it could be the processor dead. If lights and fans do go off for a split second when you turn on a motherboard with no processor, then It means my motherboard is dead and I need one of those.

Comment: When there's zero response to the "power button", then the problem is very likely something very basic. The basic power logic between the motherboard and PSU/battery is suspect.

Answer (score -1):

Because mainboards and CPUs are complex parts, different parts of them can be dead and have different symptoms.

Typically, though, nothing powering on or nothing coming on the screen is more likely to mean mainboard failure.

If a CPU is dead but the mainboard is fine, you could still see output to video and the system will inform you the CPU is missing or faulty.

Based on your description, I'd wager both your CPU and mainboard are damaged, probably because of heat.

Comment: I'd actually doubt the CPU is damaged by heat, not that it matters because on 99.9% of the laptops out there you can't remove the CPU. Well, you can, but you can't get another one back on. Almost always CPUs will trip a fault if they get too hot and shut something down. OTOH, if your 10 year old puts the incandescent lamp a little too close to the keyboard it WILL stop working. And then you find out when you replace it that not only did the keyboard warp, but that something critical underneath also got too hot because now the keyboard talks to the motherboard but the touchpad and buttons don't

Answer (score -1):

If you get *absolutely nothing* when the power button is pushed I would suspect that the motherboard is dead OR that the power switch/connections are dead. Which are probably built into the motherboard, so the motherboard is dead.

Keep in mind in the following that I spend a LOT more time buildin, fixin and worryin on servers than I do on lapdogs, or desktops, and sometimes I have to go back and catch up. Heck, I get stuck on one brand of servers for a year or three and then have to go catch up with the rest of the industry.

In general when you first power on a computer--any kind really, but most specifically computers that trace their lineage back to either the IBM PC, or the Compaq bios clone thereof, do a "POST"--that is to say a "Power On Self Test". More modern version of a "BIOS" are called "Unified Extensible Firmware Interface"[1] or "UEFI" (or sometimes just EFI) are *slightly* different but initiate some sort of power on test. More about UEFI: https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/

To go even deeper, most *hardware* initiates it's own sort of checks right away, usually via the "baseboard management controller" which you may or may not have on your laptop.

You used to be able to diagnosis what was wrong with your motherboard by "beep codes"--it would tell you if the memory was horked or whatever by the length and number of beeps.

The Macintosh did a similar thing with the startup chord--that initial BONG was the results of a POST being turned into music.

Now, the next thing to consider is that your power switch really *isn't*. It's just a signal to the BMC (above) or whatever is on your laptop, to bring the power up.

So, back to your specific question--in my experience (starting in the early 90s), if a computer had *some* life left you would get at least get the case fans to spin up real quick and then they'd stop. Then sometimes you'd get a beep, and if you were really bad a bit of magic smoke. Then you had to find a open computer store to buy a new floppy drive.

A laptop has a bit more sophisticated power system that most servers and desktops (battery, charging AND mains power) it isn't impossible that it's that subsystem that's fried and unresponsive.

The funny thing is that it *did* come back to life once. This even more makes me suspect that there's something in the power switch subsystem that ain't quite right.

Still, it's going to need a trip to somewhere where they know about your machine, and they're probably going to tell you it's dead, or that you need a new motherboard at quite some expense.

You can try to find a "used" motherboard on Ebay, or some other venues at a reduced price if you have the skill to split the case and have at it. I'm about to replace the screen on my 10 year old's computer for the second time.

[1] No, not really, but close enough for THIS discussion.